# Random in 2 cycle, do I need to reinitialize?

Tags: java, random

I have this code:

```
Random r = new Random();
while (mStack[step].hasNext()) {
int rand = r.nextInt(length);
 for (int i = rand; i < length+rand; i++) {
  //use of i and rand                 
 }
}
```

and all this in  a recursive call.

Will this seed a new Random for each while iteration, different for each recursive call?

Or I have to use

```
while (mStack[step].hasNext()) {
 Random r = new Random();
int rand = r.nextInt(length);
 for (int i = rand; i < length+rand; i++) {
  //use of i and rand                 
 }
}
```

Please advice

Comment: Did you check the outputted values for rand?

Comment: Why do you want to reseed random for each call?  That can actually lead to less random numbers - one seed should be all you need for any usage of Random, as that simply tells it where to start in the algorithm/table/etc.  Beyond that, the numbers will be pseudo-random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constant re-seeding isn't beneficial. Create a single instance of `Random`, and pass it on the stack as a parameter to the recursive method.

The no-arg `Random` constructor in Java 6 uses the sum of a instance counter and the current `System.nanoTime()` value as a seed. Of course, no re-seeding is performed by `nextInt()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the lower example. The example at the top will re-initialize with each call of the containing method. The second will do so for each item in the stack, meaning for each iteration in the loop.